# save data from apex class generated from J.S.O.N response

Tags: apex, json, wsdl, website-integration

I have got a JSON  response from  external system which consists of some data which need to be saved in sales force.

Now I have de-serialized the JSON data to apex class using some tool.

and how do I save the data from apex class to salesforce.

Any help...?

Comment: It is easy to do but first read my answer on your other question. You don't need to parse the json response. :) but if you still want to learn. post your JSON and class with this quesiton.

Comment: https://json2apex.herokuapp.com